# Swift Compiler Error at Archive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

The app builds, runs, and passes Analyze without any problems. But when I archive, 720 errors pop up. Any ideas? I've tried almost everything mentioned on SO so far.

- Cleaned, removed derived data, restarted xcode
- Set enable Modules (C and Objective-C) to NO
- Added/readded Foundation, Corefoundation, UIKit
- Swift Compiler - Code Generation (set from None to Fastest)

[image]

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443854/malformed-or-corrupted-ast-file

Comment: Yes, i tried all the steps mentioned.

Comment: @albert I can literally feel your frustration and relief hahaha. Glad you were able to fix it. I don't even remember which one of the countless things I tried solved this issue.

Comment: @Emma appears someone deleted my comments— I'm not sure on what grounds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issue was having my architectures not set to the standard. I had added i386 or something, just set it back to default xcodeproject arch and it compiled fine.