# Clean PCH files in Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have the same problem reported here:
[How to fix PCH error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463179/how-to-fix-pch-error)
But as Product > Clean Build Folder... (with Option key pressed) does not work for me I try to delete the files manually, but in the log file I am not able to see any "SharedPrecompiledHeaders" (Adam's answer), only "PrecompiledHeaders", shall I delete this ones ?

log file :

```
ProcessPCH /Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/BlinkyBle-Prefix-hgtaudjsezkfjghkrtslxkdnrhrc/BlinkyBle-Prefix.pch.pch BlinkyBle/BlinkyBle-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

    cd /Users/nullpointer/Documents/bluetooth/NORDIC/iOS-master/BlinkyBle

    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII

    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -iquote /Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/BlinkyBle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlinkyBle.build/BlinkyBle-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/BlinkyBle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlinkyBle.build/BlinkyBle-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/BlinkyBle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlinkyBle.build/BlinkyBle-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/BlinkyBle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlinkyBle.build/BlinkyBle-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/BlinkyBle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlinkyBle.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/BlinkyBle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlinkyBle.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/BlinkyBle-Prefix-hgtaudjsezkfjghkrtslxkdnrhrc/BlinkyBle-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/nullpointer/Documents/bluetooth/NORDIC/iOS-master/BlinkyBle/BlinkyBle/BlinkyBle-Prefix.pch -o /Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/BlinkyBle-Prefix-hgtaudjsezkfjghkrtslxkdnrhrc/BlinkyBle-Prefix.pch.pch --serialize-diagnostics /Users/nullpointer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlinkyBle-cjtjgkbouuqudyhjloicfilbwptx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/BlinkyBle-Prefix-hgtaudjsezkfjghkrtslxkdnrhrc/BlinkyBle-Prefix.pch.dia
```