# Xcode - I changed a hard drive, now project won't build

Tags: xcode, macos

I quickly replaced a failing hard drive. All files I checked seem ok. However, my Xcode projects won't compile. I get this message.

`error: PCH was compiled with module cache path '/Volumes/MacintoshHD2/Users/david/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2LN1PGURQ7K4J', but the path is currently '/Volumes/HD1 - DATA/Users/david/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2LN1PGURQ7K4J'`

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the old ⌥⇧⌘K?

Comment: Have you re-configured your project / re-run CMake or whatever you are using?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  ⌥⇧⌘K doesn't seem to fix it, and I don't know how to use CMake. I'm just running from Xcode..

Answer (score 6):

I just deleted my entire DerivedData folder and that did the trick for me

Comment: Thanks Roger.  I cant actually remember what I did - it was possibly your technique. But, I'm up and running..

Comment: Where is this folder found?

Comment: @Noah It's by default in the root directory of your Xcode project

Comment: I am building a react-native project, and after renaming the project, I had the same issue.  
In reacte-native 0.47, I removed the directories in ios/build/ModuleCache, and the project built..