# How do I compile PCH with a different module cache path on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pch

The initial error from Xcode was this before I changed the home folder's name:

```
<unknown>:0: error: invalid virtual filesystem overlay file '/Users/Mage's_Machine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clima-flpmhdjedajchpfzcevzpufjznko/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyJSON.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml'

<unknown>:0: error: clang importer creation failed
```

I changed the name of the home folder of my mac after knowing through some research that Xcode does not accept nonalphanumeric characters on folder names (see: Mage's_Machine)

After doing that, I got this error:

```
error: PCH was compiled with module cache path '/Users/Mage's_Machine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2RH9SWJYJWLH7', but the path is currently '/Users/Mage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2RH9SWJYJWLH7'
```

Is it correct that I changed the name of the home folder? If yes, how do I compile PCH with a different module cache path to fix this error?

I'm using Cocoapods (Alamofire, SVProgressHUD, SwiftyJSON), after changing the home folder name, I got more errors. One example of these errors:

```
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/Mage/Desktop/Clima-iOS11-master2/Pods/Target Support Files/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON-prefix.pch:2:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKitDefines.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#import <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
```

Answer (score 12):

I experienced this error after moving my `DerivedData` location, but it equally makes sense that it would happen when changing the name of a parent folder.

- Find your `DerivedData` location (listed in `Preferences > Locations`, as pictured below), and visit it in Finder by pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
- Delete the `ModuleCache` folder and rebuild your target; if it still fails, you may also need to delete the `ModuleCache.noindex` folder, too.

As far as I understand, this process rebuilds the module cache for all built modules. There's likely no need to clean all of `DerivedData`; just these particular files.

[image: DerivedData location]

Answer (score 0):

After researching more, I found the fixes for all the errors, though there are still some warnings.

Alyoshak's answer on the question on this link ([How to fix PCH error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463179/how-to-fix-pch-error)) fixed all the errors on my code.