# PCH was compiled with module cache path error

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, pch

I changed the name of my username and home folder for my Mac and now when I try building a new project I get an error during the compiling process. How would I correct this?

I already cleaned the build folder

:0: error: PCH was compiled with module cache path '/Users/edgarmartinez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/2Y7VT4EKQOHHI', but the path is currently '/Users/hannibalmartinez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/2Y7VT4EKQOHHI'

:0: error: missing required module 'SwiftShims'

Answer (score 33):

Deleting the `build` folder worked for me.

Comment: This happened with me when re-created my react-native project in a different folder and then moved to a different path. This answers helped me.

Answer (score 4):

When i move the project `ABAdressbook` to another directory, I got the following error:

```
PCH was compiled with module cache path
 '/Users/guo/Desktop/Guo/ABAdressbook/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/3D6110VGP95KX'
, but the path is currently 
'/Users/guo/Documents/Projects/ABAdressbook/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/3D6110VGP95KX'
```

Its a bit different form @Hannibal but all look like the file path is the key.

As my error point to DerivedData, so i delete this folder and rebuild it. This error disappeared.

Comment: Deleting the DerivedData worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found that changing the derived folder name like alyoshak mentioned in the answer I have linked to worked. If you go Xcode Preferences->Locations then change "DerivedData" to "DerivedData2" and switch the dropdown to relative that should make a new folder and then when you hit build it should fix your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34188668

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have SPM subdirectory in my project which had its own `.build` folder. I had to remove it, and problem gone

Comment: i am using ionic, where should i find this build folder?

Comment: else, going to try the 'delete derived data folder'

Answer (score 0):

had to go to this path '/Users/alshammari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/'
and delete everything

Answer (score 0):

When i change my project path, i get the same problem.
I deleted the `flutter_project_name/build` and `flutter_project_name/ios/DerivedData`, then it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a **Kotlin Multiplatform** project, don't forget to delete the `YourProject/shared/build` folder!